# Laravel - I have an error when I run test in laravel

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I have an error when I run my test in laravel:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

Here is the test code:

```php
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\Book;

class BookReservationTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function a_book_can_be_added_to_the_library()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $response = $this->post('/books', [
            'title' => 'cool book title',
            'author' => 'victor'
        ]);
        $response->assertOk();
        $this->assertCount(11, Book::all());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide you database configuration? Which database driver are you trying to use?

Comment: @Sebastian I used mysql data base.

Comment: Interestingly `PRAGMA foreign_keys=1` (or `ON`) is an SQLite pragma.